# android studio set proxy

Tags: android, android-studio

[I set the proxy like the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mh5Jk.png)[it seems connection successfully][2][But I cannot update or download SDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRvmX.png)

please tell me why,thanks

Answer (score 0):

Even though you have set the proxy, sometimes SDK sites are not accessible from with in an organisation, try connecting to the open Internet (outside your organisation network/intranet) and then try updating your SDK.